# Running query from Amplab-shark to cassandra on hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, apache-spark, shark-sql

Please help needed for Amplab-Shark query on cassandra in hdfs.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/task/JobContextImpl
```

I can successfully run:

- use database
- show tables;
- etc.

But can not run any select statement i.e:

`select * from table;`

I get the following error:

```
shark> select * from call limit 1;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce    /task/JobContextImpl
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getInputFormatClass(Table.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.<init>(Table.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:892)
    at     org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1083)
    at     org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1059)
    at     shark.parse.SharkSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SharkSemanticAnalyzer.scala:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:279)
    at shark.SharkDriver.compile(SharkDriver.scala:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:909)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver.processCmd(SharkCliDriver.scala:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver$.main(SharkCliDriver.scala:233)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver.main(SharkCliDriver.scala)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 17 more
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the full config and how you set up the tables for a better answer. Just looking at the error it seems like you are missing some hadoop jars on your classpath